# Python Dill or Pickle gives error when use in a new file

Tags: google-colaboratory, pickle, recommendation-engine, cosine-similarity, dill

I need help with my code. I have built a recommendation system using cosine similarity on a colab and used pickle to serialized it. when I deserialized it inside a colab file, it works perfectly fine but when I deserialize it in a new colab file. it gives me an error

```
name 'data' is not defined
```

data is a variable that is initialized with my dataset which is outside of the class InstaPost.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction import text
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import dill as pickle


data = pd.read_csv("/content/instaData.txt")
data

data = data[["Caption", "Hashtags"]]


captions = data["Caption"].tolist()
uni_tfidf = text.TfidfVectorizer(input=captions, stop_words="english")
uni_matrix = uni_tfidf.fit_transform(captions)
uni_sim = cosine_similarity(uni_matrix)

def recommend_post(x):
  return ", ".join(data["Caption"].loc[x.argsort()[-7:-1]])

data["Recommended Post"] = [recommend_post(x) for x in uni_sim]


class InstaPost:

    def Post(number):
      count = 0
      wordy = (data["Recommended Post"][number])
      sentence = wordy.split(',')
      
      for i in sentence:
        count=count+1
        print(count," ",i)

obj = InstaPost

obj.Post(1)
```

```
pickle_out = open("modelREC", "wb")
pickle.dump(obj, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

```
pickle_in = open("modelREC", "rb")
exe = pickle.load(pickle_in)


print(exe.Post(10))
```

NOTE: on a different file

```
print(exe.Post)
```

works

and give output

```
<function InstaPost.Post at 0x7efc0b4c3f70>
```

if I need to give the reference of the data than please guide me how should I do it. It will be a great help to me

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm the `dill` author.  You are pickling a class method that includes a pointer reference to `data` -- thus you'll need to also include `data` in your pickle.  You can either use a serializing mechanism that uses reference tracing (e.g. `dill` with `recurse=True`), or better yet, include the data you need in the class instance as an attribute. Alternately, you can also pickle the data to the file with a second dump... and then it will load first and the method with reference it when  your method loads.

Comment: Thanks you for a very quick response. you suggestion worked. thanks alott